# Passing parameters in self action:@selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsindexpath

I am trying to add a NSIndexpath as parameter to a method through

```
[self action:@selector(showDetailedImage)];
```

Is it possible to add an extra parameter(`NSIndexPath`) to this method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No, you can not pass arguments**, you can only show that this selector will take that many numbers of arguments.

If you need to do this, you can create a property and access it from the method `showDetailedImage`.

However you can use this selector:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(showDetailedImageIndex:) withObject:objectOfNSIndex];
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. on query i have is - create a property, you mean create a NSIndexpath *indexpath in headerfile and then assign the value in implementation class and access within the method.  correct me if am wrong.

Comment: Yes you are correct except you need to do as otherwide it will be ivar or a global `@property(strong) NSIndexpath *indexpath;`

Answer (score 0):

Make a wrapper(another method) say `-(void)wrapperMethodOforiginalSelectorMethod;` of your *now-selector-method*  say `-(void)originalSelectorMethod:(id)argument;` and make the wrapper as your new selector which further calls your originalSelectorMethod with your argument.

Answer (score -5):

You have to add extra parameter to

ShowDetailedImage:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

can call [self action:@selector(showDetailedImage:)];

Comment: I tried it, but its not working. The error message displayed is "Expected :"